# how can i translate c# funcion to excel

Tags: excel

I am new to functions in excel (I am c# developer).
I got a function that my boss told me to write and I have no clue in excel(VBA?).

This is the question:

1 xlsx file, with 2 tabs:
[image]

Each tab contains a table with 3 columns:
Name, id, yesOrNo(string)

- yesOrNo(string) column in “a” tab is empty (at first)
  I need to fill it with data from the table in “b” tab

Tab "a":
[image]

Tab “b”:
[image]

•   In Each table there can be lot of rows...

The function need to do that(I’ll write an pseudo code in c#):

```
•   a=tab a
•   b= tab b
•   a.name = tab “a” column “name”

function ab(){
    For(i=2; I < a.name.length; i++){
        For(j=2; j < a.name.length; j++){
            if( b.name[j].contains(a.name[i]) ){
                if(a.id[i] == b.id[j]){
                    b.yesOrNo(string)[i] = a.yesOrNo(string)[j];
                }
            }
       }
    }    
}
```

So in the end, table in tab a will look like this:

[image: tab b]

Is there any way to convert c# code o vba?
Where should I actually  write the code?

Comment: So tab A becomes a copy of tab B?

Comment: no. i need to copy the`yesOrNo(string)` column, based on the conditions i wrote in pseudo code, to the outcome will look like the last picture for example)

Comment: I'm saying the outcome is just tab B

Comment: yes if i got you right.. there are 2 tabs `a` and `b`

Comment: i mean that the outcome is just based on data in tab b

Comment: Wondn't a simple Lookup (`VLookup` or `XLookup` depending on your version) of ID do the trick?

Comment: @chrisneilsen Yes, if it will work.. do you have a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I eventually solved this:

- click on the column that you want the result to appear
- write this formula `=XLOOKUP(B1,'b'!B:B,'b'!C:C)`

Explanation:

`xlookup( the value you eant to search, where do you want to search, what resuls to show )`

- the answer based ov the images i adde added in the question body.
- be sure that you have XLOOKUP installed, I downloaded it according to this video:
  [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j-E_nfxqc-Q&ab_channel=STB81)

** I am not sure why it wasn't installed already, I am using office 2019..

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim lastrowA As Long
    Dim lastrowB As Long
    Dim rowA As Long
    Dim rowB As Long
    Dim nameA As String
    Dim nameB As String
    
    ' Get last row on sheet A
    lastrowA = Worksheets("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).row
    
    ' Get last row on sheet B
    lastrowB = Worksheets("B").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).row
    
    ' For each row on sheet A
    For rowA = 2 To lastrowA
        
        ' Get name (A)
        nameA = Worksheets("A").Cells(rowA, 1).Value
        
        ' For each row on sheet B
        For rowB = 2 To lastrowB
        
            ' get name (B) 
            nameB = Worksheets("B").Cells(rowB, 1).Value

            ' if name (B) starts with name (A)...
            If Mid(nameB, 1, Len(nameA)) = nameA Then
            
                ' Update yes or no
                Worksheets("A").Cells(rowA, 3).Value = Worksheets("B").Cells(rowB, 3).Value
                
                ' Exit inner for loop 
                Exit For
                
            End If
            
        Next rowB
        
    Next rowA
    
End Sub
```

Where should you write the code? (1) Alt+F11 to open the VBA editor. (2) In the project explorer, right click, Insert Module. (3) Paste the code into the new module.

You can run it by (1) Select developer tab, (2) click macros button, (3) select the macro and click Run.

Comment: my boss said to me that's too complicated and he think that if i use the function xlookup i can probably do it in one row of code.. is there a way?

Comment: "do it in one line of code" was not in the original ask, and if it had been, I would not have taken the trouble to respond.

Comment: sorry, but i didn't know about the existence of `xlookup` function, it does'nt exist in c#.. sorry again- i will try to find the way with `xlookup` if it possible.